# How to get MultiPolygon from MultiPoint for area calculation in Postgis?

Tags: postgis, polygon, point, geometry, area

I have PostGIS database table with `geometry` records containing `MultiPoint`. When I try `st_area(geometry)`, I get 0. How to convert it to `MultiPolygon` to calculate covered area if we assume that a point covers specific radius?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your points is ordered so they define a polygon, you can combine

[ST_LineFromMultiPoint](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.4/ST_LineFromMultiPoint.html)

with

[ST_Polygon](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.4/ST_Polygon.html)

You will not get a multipolygon from this but a polygon.

To build a multipolygon which actually have more than 1 part you will need to define how the points shall be divided into sub polygon parts. But I guess that is not what you want.

**Update**

To add the first point at the end of the linestring to get a closed ring you can do something like:

```
WITH a AS 
(SELECT 'multipoint(1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 2 1)'::geometry p)
,b AS
(SELECT ST_LineFromMultiPoint(p) l FROM a)
SELECT ST_Polygon(ST_AddPoint(l, ST_PointN(l,1)), 32633) l FROM b;
```

Comment: I don't get Polygon because of "ERROR:  lwpoly_from_lwlines: shell must be closed"

Comment: Ah yes you are right. You will need to add the first point also as last point

Comment: Now experimenting with ST_ConvexHull(geom), it returns Polygon.

Comment: yes, but only convex polygon

Comment: st_convexhull and st_concavehull may cover too much area which is far away from points. Checking ST_Buffer.

Answer (score 0):

[ST_Buffer](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) solved the problem:

> Returns a geometry covering all points within a given distance from
>   the input geometry.

`ST_Buffer(geom::geography, 7)` outputs points with specified radius:

[image]

`ST_Concavehull(geom, 1)` covers too much unrelated area:

[image]

Comment: In what way does that solve your problem? I thought you wanted the area of the polygon. From those buffered points you will just get the area of a bunch of buffered points.

Comment: Did you see my update on the answer, how to connect the start and end of the linestring to get a closed ring, which can become a polygon

Comment: Yes, you get polygon from ST_Buffer, but it is a polygon describing a wide boundary in your case since the points seems to be closer than  your buffer. But you still don't get the area inside the boundary. So, if it was the area of an approx 7 units wide boundary you wanted you are correct, but then the question is very unclear. If you actually want the area inside your points (the polygon defined by your points) then ST_Buffer gives you a totally wrong answer.

Comment: Sorry, it was unclear formulation of the question. I was searching how to get a Polygon or MultiPolygon. I have MultiPoint and I needed to calculate the covered area if we assume that point covers some radius.

Comment: I think you are confusing the convex and concave hulls. The concave hull, by definition, is the smallest area that contains all the points. So, wrap the answer of Nicklas in ST_ConcaveHull and you get what you need. Note, that you need to play with the 2nd parameter, if you set it close to 1, you will get the  convex hull, which is exactly what you have done.

Comment: Why not just use the polygon that gets defined by the points? If they are in the right order, which they seem to be from the wide boundary built in the picture 1 above.